# Aircraft with missing wing part

Tags: set-identification

I have the body and a 1 side of a wing span, missing the other side. There is a cylindrical thingy with a light lime green "cap". There is also a winch inside the body.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Please add a photograph (or two) of the incomplete set. The text description is just not enough.